# place several instances of a movieclip on stage AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, movieclip

I'm making a First Person Shooter game in flash AS3. I'm still learning AS3 and need help. I have a movieclip 'Player' thats placed on the stage at the start, it can shoot and move so far, but I need enemies for the player to shoot at.

I have created an enemy and need help getting multiple instances of the same movieclip (the enemy) to spawn off stage and movie towards the 'Player' movieclip. I believe I need to create an array to get 2 or more of the same movieclip on that stage at any one point in time but I'm completely stuck on how to do this.

Thanks in advanced.

Links to my code are [Here](http://pastebin.com/W8kYLyUX)
(Please note 'Baddy.as' I know is spelt wrong and also it's now been changed to 'Enemy.as')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have your Enemy class you can just create multiple instances of it and store them in an array.

```
var enemies:Array =  [];
var enemy:Enemy = new Enemy();
stage.addChild(enemy);
enemies.push(enemy);
```

Then you can loop through the enemies and move them using the `enemies` array.

```
for(var i=0; i<enemies.length; ++i)
{
    move(enemies[i]);
}
```

Comment: Would this work for all the enemy's on the stage at any one time? I.e all enemy's on the left, right, above and below? Because I think the only way to get them to move towards the player movieclip is to get the players position and put into a var (and loop this every frame so that it constantly has the correct value), then set a speed for the enemies and use the var to tell it where the should be moving to (unsure if this needs looping)? And I'm not sure which class I should type it into (main or enemy) I guessing main but by enemy class is empty. I'm still very new to actionscript.

Comment: It will work as long as you put all your enemies in the array. To move the enemies toward the player you need to figure out where the player is relative to the enemies.

Comment: I just remembered I already have an array in my code for the 'Bullet's .... I'm still learning AS3 but is the `i` in square braces in this statement `move(enemies[i]);` a variable? I'm asking because the other array has `i` as a variable in the conditions of the `for loop`, having both as `i` would completely throw it off would it not?

Comment: Yes the `i` is a variable and no it won't throw it off since `i` is initialized to 0 in the loop. If both loops are in the same scope you can take out the `var i` out of the loop and just leave `i = 0` in the loop body.

Comment: Okay thanks, I changed the I var in this loop to b, and it seems to be working well. Thanks for your help.